# Duda refrescar conexión SQL en Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Muy buenas, tengo una duda con el uso de SQL y JAVA. Mi programa se basa en una única conexión a un servidor SQL y mediante esa conexión hago consultas. La duda viene a la hora de refrescar esa conexión, ¿Es posible que se cierre? En ese caso, como hago para que no se cierre? La conexión la realizo de esta manera:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class Conexion {
    Connection conectar;
   
  
   
    String usuario=*****;
    String contrasenia=*****;    
    String bd=*****;
    String ip=*****;
    String puerto=*****;
    
    String cadena = "jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+puerto+"/"+bd+"?useSSL=false&connectTimeout=5000";
    
    public Connection estableceConexion(){
    
        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conectar = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena,usuario,contrasenia);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se conectó correcta a la Base de DATOS");
            
            setCarpetaDestino(Destino);
            setDireccionEscritorio(Escritorio);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problemas en la conexion"+ e.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return conectar;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Es posible que se cierre?

Si por cualquier cosa se puede cerrar la conexión (Desastre natural, error humano, etc).

> En ese caso, como hago para que no se cierre?

Lo que debes asegurarte en si es que tus datos se procesen y de esta forma cerrar tu mismo la conexión. Para mayor seguridad puedes estudiar lo que son [transacciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) con esto te asegurar que se procese todo o nada.

Acá un ejemplo simple:

```java
try
{
   DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver());
            
            // Se obtiene una conexión con la base de datos. Hay que
            // cambiar el usuario "root" y la clave "la_clave" por las
            // adecuadas a la base de datos que estemos usando.
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection (
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba","root", "la_clave");
            
            // Se crea un Statement, para realizar la consulta
            Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
            
            // Se realiza la consulta. Los resultados se guardan en el 
            // ResultSet rs
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("select * from persona");
            
            // Se recorre el ResultSet, mostrando por pantalla los resultados.
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println (rs.getInt ("Id") + " " + rs.getString (2)+ 
                    " " + rs.getDate(3));
            }
} catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
   //cerramos la conexion a la db
   conexion.close();
}
```

> De lo que veo en tu código estas retornando la conexión

```java
//donde uses el objeto por ejemplo:
Conexion data = new Conexion();
Statement s = data.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("select * from persona");
data.close();
```

Este ejemplo lo saqué de este [blog](https://old.chuidiang.org/java/mysql/EjemploJava.php)

Espero te sirva saludos. ✌

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si solvento tu pregunta para poder ayudar al resto de personas en caso que necesiten. 